# Use Azure Bicep module to output the resourceId of all frontend IP configurations linked to a named load balancer

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-bicep

I'm trying to write a module that will get me the resource IDs of all PublicIp resources in the front-end IP configuration of a named load balancer.

My starting point is an array of AKS cluster names. I've got as far as being able to output the first ID, but not all:

```
resource loadBalancers 'Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers@2022-09-01' existing = [for (aksCluster, i) in aksCluster: {
  name: 'kubernetes'
  scope: resourceGroup('mc_${aksCluster.name}-rg_${aksCluster.name}_${aksCluster.location}')
}]

var frontendIPConfigurations = [for (aksCluster, i) in aksCluster: {
  data: loadBalancers[i].properties.frontendIPConfigurations[0].id
}]

output ipConfigs array = frontendIPConfigurations
```

See how in the second `for` loop I have to reference the item at index `0`. I can't find a way to return an array of all IDs here. Is this not possible or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: my guess is - you need another var with another loop. btw, why do you want that info? those are managed by aks, you shouldn't alter them

Comment: All this is because I need the resource ID of the DNS-enabled PublicIp resource that lives in my cluster resource group but has an unpredictable name. This is in order to attach it as an endpoint of a traffic manager. Because the name is unpredictable my only option is to read it from the configuration of the AKS load balancer. But I'm thinking it may be easier to get this name outside of Bicep and feed it in.